# WSO2 IS Entitlement Policy Name length restriction

Tags: wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

When I use the Simple Policy Editor to create a new XACML Policy the value for the Entitlement Policy Name text box appears to be limited to 20 characters. Is there a configuration option to change that will allow for longer values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not configurable. It's in [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/8cd996c1dc6d9e7c0df491322af6e9ddf1cf3709/components/entitlement/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui/src/main/resources/web/entitlement/simple-policy-editor.jsp#L134) JSP page. Your policy name should match following regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{3,20}$/
```